# C++ HashTable Question

Tags: c++

If I use an array of linked list to implement a hash table, the "remove" function might require traversing through a "chain."

Is this also true for "deleting"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it applies to anything you try to do with the hash table.  Remove, delete (which sound like the same thing to me), insert, search, you name it.

Comment: What if i use an array of linked list to implement a hash table, my function, "add", could be implemented in a way that requires no probing???

Comment: Yeah I guess that's true, as long as you're willing to use linear search on the chains.  You could just add your new item to the head of the chain.

Comment: Thanks Carl, I just have one last question: When and If I use the linked list method, will i have direct access to the beginning of each individual chain?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Nearly any operation may require following these chains. The key is to select a table size and hash function such that chains are typically short (ideally, nearly all of them should have no more than one item).